# Getting $injector:modulerr error using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the following error while loading the page using angular.js.

> Error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=Channabasavashwara&…20at%20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Foditek.in%2FGofast%2Fjs%2Fangularjs.js%3A19%3A463)
```

I am explaining my code below.

> loginRoute.js:

```
var Admin=angular.module('Channabasavashwara',['ngRoute']);
Admin.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/dashboard',{
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'dashboardController'
    });
})
```

> loginController.js:

```
var loginAdmin=angular.module('Channabasavashwara',[]);
loginAdmin.controller('loginController',function($scope,$http,$window){
    $scope.user_login=function(){
    if($scope.user_name==''){
        alert('user name filed should not keep blank');
    }else if($scope.user_pass==''){
        alert('password filed should not keep blank');
    }else{
        var userData={'user_name':$scope.user_name,'user_pass':$scope.user_pass};
        console.log('user',userData);
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "php/Login/login.php",
            data: userData,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            console.log('response',response);
            alert(response.data['msg']);
            location.href='dashboard/';
        },function errorCallback(response) {
            alert(response.data['msg']);
        });
    }
    }
});
```

If i am removing the `loginRoute.js` link from index page this error is not coming. But here imy requirement is user will forwarded to another(`i.e-dashboard`) page after successfull login.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: use this  angular.module('Channabasavashwara').controller()

Comment: Have you included js file for ng-route module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add require dependancy in controller to inject.

Replace
`loginAdmin.controller('loginController',function($scope,$http,$window){`

To

`loginAdmin.controller('loginController',['$scope','$http','$window',function($scope,$http,$window){`

and replace `var loginAdmin=angular.module('Channabasavashwara',[]);`

to

`var loginAdmin=angular.module('Channabasavashwara');`

Comment: @ Sarjan : I added as per you but still its throwing another error but 1st error has gone.Error-` http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/ng/areq?p0=loginController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20string`

Comment: Varity that you have added all `js` file in index.html...and check the updated answer

Comment: @ Sarjan : I updated as per you but still error was there.After removing `'$scope','$http','$window'` from line `loginAdmin.controller('loginController','$scope','$http','$window',function($scope,$http,$window){` and made it to `loginAdmin.controller('loginController',function($scope,$http,$window){` it worked properly.

Comment: @ Sarjan : another one problem it is not redirecting to dashboard page and showing error `The requested URL /Gofast/dashboard was not found on this server.`

Comment: @ Sarjan : No,If i am doing as per you after successfully login the url is becoming `http://oditek.in/dashboard` which is wrong,It should `http://oditek.in/Gofast/dashboard` like this.Here i need when user will logged in he will move to another page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91356/discussion-between-satya-and-sarjan-desai).